# How to name build steps in Buildbot

Tags: buildbot

I have Buildbot set up on a Windows 7 machine that's set to run a series of tests when I check in python code to a git repo. When I check on the build details via the web interface it displays a set of build steps that have been run as defined in my master.cfg configuration file.

Currently I have several shell command steps that each run a windows .bat file. Each of these steps is sequentially titled "shell", "shell_1", "shell_2", etc. Is there a way to re-name these steps (i.e. "format_check", "unittest", etc.)? I don't see an option to name build steps in the "[build steps](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html)" section of the buildbot documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you just add it as a parameter in the call to addStep: e.g. `name="step_name"`

Updating the referenced documentation's examples to include a name parameter:

```
f.addSteps([
    steps.SVN(repourl="http://svn.example.org/Trunk/", name="svn"),
    steps.ShellCommand(command=["make", "all"], name="make"),
    steps.ShellCommand(command=["make", "test"], name="test")
```